# read and parse cookie

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Okey im pretty new to php/javascript but what i would need to do is read cookie and then parse some part of it. How can i do it easily? php or javascript or okey.

Cookie has something like this info: ssf.2313.1333 and I would need to get middle numrbers (2313).

Comment: Do you need it in PHP or Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using PHP easily.

```
$pieces = explode('.',$_COOKIE['yourcookiename']);
echo $pieces[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to create the cookie, I would suggest serializing an array with data. This way, you have far more control when reading the cookie.

Example:

```
$information = array(
    'one' => 'data1',
    'two' => 'data2'
);
$ck = setcookie('cookiename', serialize($information), time()+3600);
```

When fetching the cookie, use the PHP function unserialize, like so:

```
$ck = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookiename']);
echo $ck['one']; // returns 'data1'
```